# add pagination to php - xml file

Tags: php, xml, pagination

There are many threads here about adding pagination to a php file showing XML data, but none of the codes seem to work.

This is what I have so far:

```
 <?php
 $xml_data = simplexml_load_file("https://www.website.com/file.xml")
 or die("Error: Object Creation failure");
 foreach ($xml_data->children() as $data)
 {
     if (str_contains($data->category, 'Lotions')) {
         echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
             echo "<div class='item-xml'>";
                 echo "<div class='title-xml'>$data->title</div>";
                 echo "<img class='image-xml' src='{$data->images[0]->image->location}'>";
                 echo "<div class='price-xml'>€ $data->price</div>";
                 echo "<a href='$data->link' target='_blank'><div class='link-xml'></div></a>";
             echo "</div>";
         echo "</div>";
     }
 }
 ?>
```

How do I add pagination (30 products per page) with navigation under them, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "continue" to skip showing items. It's not an optimized solution But considering that you are using external dynamic file, that would be good enough.

For example, if the total count of feed items is 50, and you want to show 10 item each page, you should add 5 pageKey and a counter to your "foreach" loop.

When user try to see page 1, first 10 items will be showed and other items will be skipped with continue.

When user try to see page 2, first 10 items will be skipped with continue, next 10 item will be showed, and other items will be skipped with continue.

When user try to see page 3, first 20 items will be skipped with continue, next 10 item will be showed, and other items will be skipped with continue.

And so on until the last page and last 10 items.

Something like this. Notice that I didn't have enough time to test the code, but structure od code is fine, you just need to check any possible typo.

```
<?php

$eachpage = 10;
$xml_data = simplexml_load_file("https://www.example.com/file.xml") or die("Error: Object Creation failure");

$total = 0;
foreach ($xml_data->children() as $data) {
    if (strpos($data->category, 'Lotions')) $total++;
}

$page = $_GET['page'];
if ($page <= 1) $page = 1;

$num = 0;
foreach ($xml_data->children() as $data) {
    if (strpos($data->category, 'Lotions')) {
        
        $num++;
        
        if ($num > (($page - 1) * $eachpage) and $num <= ($page * $eachpage)) {
            echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
            echo "<div class='item-xml'>";
            echo "<div class='title-xml'>$data->title</div>";
            echo "<img class='image-xml' src='{$data->images[0]->image->location}'>";
            echo "<div class='price-xml'>€ $data->price</div>";
            echo "<a href='$data->link' target='_blank'><div class='link-xml'></div></a>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}

for($i=1; $i<=ceil($total/$eachpage); $i++) {
    echo '<a href="?page=' . $i . '"> page ' . $i . '</a>'; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @harif but how does that look like in php? I am a total dummy in that language.

Comment: I edit my answer and add a sample code. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Hanif. Please remove the XML url name.

Comment: shoot! sorry :)